# Missing hard drives

Tags: hardware

Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Two 1tb hard drives previously listed are now missing.
as root, /media/*/ list only an external 250gb hard drive.
Gparted list them as /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc
However, there is no means to access them.

How are the two 1tb hard drives made available?

Now, I'm in big trouble.
W10 was previously installed and removed.
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was installed.
The two hard drives are NTFS drives containing needed data.
They did show up at first. Now, they do not.

Comment: Did you install partition tables on the drives (will wipe the drive) and create ext4 or NTFS partitions? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Biit from a LiveUSB.

In [gparted](https://gparted.org), select the drive to change with the spin box at upper right.

Then, under the button bar, you will see one or more lines for that drive to show what it finds there. If there's a 'key' icon in the second column, that partition is locked and must be unlocked before it can be changed.

Right-click on each
[image]
and then from the Context Menu as shown either unmount it or (for the swap partition), pick *swapoff*.

If the line shows unallocated, it is ready to partition and format.

If the line does not show as unallocated, select it then choose Delete.

Mark everything you wish to delete or resize, then click on the green checkmark above the Button Bar to proceed with making changes.

Once you have unallocated space, click on **New** in the Menu bar, then add the partition details as you like, then press the green checkmark to make the changes.

Once a drive has been formatted for Linux, you can put files there.